# Embedding aspx website page in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gis

I have normal ASP.NET MVC application , in which I want embedd aspx application . I have geomedia portal published on  server  and want to embed that portal on MVC application

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you need to embed any hosted page/site in your site, use Iframe.

Comment: As @AbhishekTomar said, iframes are commonly used to reference .aspx pages from within razor/mvc. All you need to do is set the `src` attribute of your iframe to the aspx page you want to display

Comment: Yes, Thanks @GregH for detailed information.

Comment: Maybe consider using an iframe?